# Plotting from large Dataset in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am facing a collection of `50000` data points (incurred losses in insurance) and want to find a fitting distribution. Since I would like to make a plot in python it is not working - but it should be very simple e.g. making a `plot` of the first `500` incurred losses :

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
plt.hist(df[1:500], bins='auto')
```

but the `plot` is empty.

What do you think?

Thank you in advance and kind regards :)

Comment: please provide a sample of the data

Comment: due to data protection I am not quite sure, if I can provide you with the exact data, but : it's a list containing 52000 entries in the range of 20$ up to 3.000.000$. The aggregation of the data should be done automatically with bins='auto' ....

Comment: just add some random data that will reproduce your problem, if you can't add the actual data that you are using.

Comment: Hi, maybe its usefull to group the losses before?
like: group 1 : 0-500$
group 2: 501-1000$ and so on
is this possible via the groupby function?